# LoL VS event 2018 last Darius quest

Tags: league-of-legends

Alright, according to the official [website](https://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/special-event/learn-more-vs-2018-event), one has to "Be on the team that destroyed the first tower on Summoner's Rift" to complete the last quest. Since I just did that and also won the game, I am wondering if that quests excludes URF and is only completable in normal games.

Does anyone has more details about this quest or an idea how it exactly works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be bugged - I can confirm that ARURF does not count towards the completion of this quest. Both myself and a friend of mine have both had the exact same problem, where we win a game of ARURF which satisfies the requirements yet we don't get the unlock.

All other matchmade Summoner's Rift game modes should count, however. This includes Co-Op Vs. AI games, which is a quick and guaranteed way of finishing the quest.

Comment: Can confirm that Co-Op vs AI works fine